# ¿Como cambiar de jPanel desde un boton que se encuntra en un jPanel diferente?

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

Tengo una clase jFrame en la que a su vez tiene un jPanel llamado "inicio" que con un boton llama a otro jPanel llamado "Opciones" hasta ahi todo bien, el caso es que ese jPanel "Opciones" tiene otro boton con el que vuelve al jPanel "inicio" este ultimo no consigo que funcione, dicho boton se encuentra en la clase Opciones con el nombre de "atras".
He intentado crear en la clase Opciones, una variable del tipo Inicio con la que mediante el evento del boton hacer no visible al jPanel Opciones y hacer visible al jPanel Inicio, pero me devuelve un error "NullPointerException"

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu menuPrincipal=new Menu();
    menuPrincipal.setVisible(true);
    menuPrincipal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Clase del jFrame

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private Inicio inicio;
private Opciones opciones;
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Menu() {
    setTitle("Vagabundo");
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Menu.class.getResource("/imagenes/icono.png")));
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    contentPane.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    //Jpanel principal
    inicio=new Inicio();
    inicio.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    inicio.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    getContentPane().add(inicio);
    GridBagLayout gbl_inicio = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_inicio.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 53};
    inicio.setLayout(gbl_inicio);
    //Jpanel opciones
    opciones=new Opciones();

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Jugar");
    btnNewButton_2.setBackground(new Color(173, 255, 47));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton_2.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnNewButton_2.gridy = 1;
    inicio.add(btnNewButton_2, gbc_btnNewButton_2);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Opciones");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                inicio.setVisible(false);
                getContentPane().add(opciones);
                opciones.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBackground(new Color(100, 149, 237));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 1;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 1;
    inicio.add(btnNewButton, gbc_btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Salir");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBackground(new Color(240, 128, 128));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton_1.gridx = 2;
    gbc_btnNewButton_1.gridy = 1;
    inicio.add(btnNewButton_1, gbc_btnNewButton_1);
}
```

Clase Inicio

```
public class Inicio extends JPanel {

private Image fondo;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    File fondoMenu=new File("src/imagenes/fondo.png");
    try{
        fondo=ImageIO.read(fondoMenu);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("La imagen para el fondo de menu no se encuentra ");
    }
g.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), null);
}
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public Inicio() {

}
```

Clase Opciones

```
public class Opciones extends JPanel {
private Image fondo;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    File fondoMenu=new File("src/imagenes/fondo.png");
    try{
        fondo=ImageIO.read(fondoMenu);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("La imagen para el fondo de menu no se encuentra ");
    }
g.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), null);
}
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public Opciones() {
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JButton btnAtras = new JButton("Atras");
    btnAtras.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnAtras.setBackground(new Color(250, 128, 114));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnAtras = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnAtras.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnAtras.gridx = 1;
    gbc_btnAtras.gridy = 2;
    add(btnAtras, gbc_btnAtras);

}
```